# How to create Singleton service in Angular 2 and read URL Params

Tags: javascript, angular, service, singleton

Im reading an url of the app http://localhost/?config=preprod

Im trying to create a Singleton service which reads **UrlParameters.js** and exposes `get(key)` method. Which stores `config=preprod`
Similar below (from my Angular 1.x singleton service)

```
get: function (key) {
            if (!params) {
                params = {};
                var queryString = window.location.search.substring(1);
                _(queryString.split('&')).each(function (param) {
                    var val = param.split('=');
                    params[val[0]] = val[1];
                });
            }
            return params[key];
        }
```

Now, I think I also will need access to Route params inside this service in Angular 2, since I cannot do the in Angular 2.

Also, I need to share this UrlParams singleton with another Singleton service called Flag. Which reads Flag.get('config')
Something like below (extracted from my Angular 1.x project)
**Flag.js**

```
set: function (flag) {
            if (UrlParameter.get(flag)) {
                localStorage.setItem(flag, UrlParameter.get(flag));
            }
        },
        get: function (flag) {
            return localStorage.getItem(flag);
        }
```

Comment: Services provided in `@NgModule()` of `AppModule` are singletons.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer you mean should I declare them inside `providers: [],` ?

Comment: Not sure what you men with `declare`, but it's not a service if it is not registered in `providers: []` anywhere.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can you also help me on loading ActivatedRoute inside Service, and then called by another service

Comment: I don't know what that means. What are you trying to accomplish with `ActivatedRoute`. You can get most things by injecting `Router` and using `Rotuer.routerState` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterState-interface.html

Comment: I just want to read URL Parameters e.g. `www.mywebapp.com/?config=preprod&token=acxlkdnl249054i09t`

Comment: The example in the link shows it. Just use `queryParams` instead of `params`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137025/discussion-between-steel-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: You're looking for the [location service.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Location-class.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by @JordanFrankfurt I used Location service, and fits my purpose. Also Thanks to @Günter Zöchbauer for the efforts.

Below is my UrlParams Service which is been also added in NgModule under `providers`

`url-parameter.service.ts`

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import {LocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class UrlParameterService {
  public params = null;

  constructor(private location: LocationStrategy) {}

  get(key:string):String {
    debugger;
    if (!this.params) {
      this.params = {};
      var queryString = this.location.path();
      queryString.split('&').forEach((param) => {
        var val = (param.indexOf('?') ? param.slice(param.indexOf('?')+1).split('=') : param.split('='));
        this.params[val[0]] = val[1];
      });
    }
    return this.params[key] || false;
  }

}
```

Comment: So the idea is create a service using `@Injectable()` list it under `provider` array. correct?

Answer (score 4):

I would try to stay within the Angular 2 conventions, but if you simply want an instance of something you've instantiated outside of Angular 2 conventions, it's pretty simple.

```
var UrlParameters = function() {

    this.instance  = this;
    this.params = null;

    this.get = function(key) {
        if (!this.params){

        params = {};

            var queryString = window.location.search.substring(1);

            _(queryString.split('&')).each(function (param) {
                var val = param.split('=');
                params[val[0]] = val[1];
            });

            this.params = params;

        }

        return this.params[key];
    };

    this.set = function() {

    }
}

var Flag = {
    set: function (flag) {
            var urlParams = UrlParameter.getInstance();

            if (urlParams.get(flag)) {
                localStorage.setItem(flag, UrlParameter.get(flag));
            }
        }
}
```

TypeScript version

```
class UrlParameter {

    static instance:UrlParameter;

    constructor() {
        UrlParameter.instance = this;
    }

    get( key: string) : string {
    //  ... 
    }
}

class Flag {

    set(key:string) : string {
        if (UrlParameter.instance.get(key)){
            // you have it
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This might do what you want:

```
@Injectable() 
class MyService {
  constructor(router:Router) {
    this.router.events
    .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .forEach(e => {
       var config = router.routerState.root.snapshot.param['config'];
       console.log(config);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: doesnt work. Since router event is not initialized before its called

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your comment. What is "its"?

Comment: The Router service doesnt work for me. Im using location service now instead.